# Avoiding explicit functor template type

Tags: c++, templates, functor

I'm playing with functors. I'm using the standard example below:

```
class C {
public:
    template <typename Func>
    void foo(Func fun)
    {
        fun();
    }
};

struct S {
    void operator()() { printf ("in S\n"); }
};
....
C myClass;
myClass.foo (S());
```

This works nicely and I don't need to explicitly provide the S template type in the call to foo(), it just figures it out. But suppose I want to store the functor as a member variable and call it later:

```
class C {
public:
    template <typename Func>
    void foo(Func fun) {
        _myFunc = fun;
    }

    void someOtherThing() { 
        _myFunc();
    }
private:
    WHAT_IS_THIS_TYPE _myFunc;
};
```

Do I now need to make the whole class a template? If so, can the compiler infer the template type as it did with the single functor, or must I provide it explicitly? Thanks.

Comment: You can make the whole class a template, and provide a function that deduces the type of the function object.

Comment: @Xeo - yeah, that was my first suggestion, but then I deleted my answer, because the topic says: "Avoiding explicit functor template type".

Comment: @Kiril: Read again, I accidentally hit enter too soon. :)

Comment: @Xeo - o, I see, sorry :) But then the type must be specified explicitly during the creation of the object OR there must be some constructor, taking the "functor" and storing it.

Comment: @Kiril: [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95f9d1b8f4100d07) is what I meant.

Comment: @Xeo - aha, I get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use std::function (in C++11) or boost::function to store callable objects (functions, functors). It implements type erasure pattern.

```
class C {
public:
  template <typename Func>
  void foo(Func fun) {
    _myFunc = fun;
  }

  void someOtherThing() { 
    _myFunc();
  }
private:

  std::function<void()> _myFunc;
};
```

Comment: Don't use type-erasure without any need for it. It's not clear if the OP wouldn't be able to use something like `auto c = make_C(S());`.

Comment: The question is titled "Avoiding explicit functor template type". I think it's pretty clearly suggested that he does not want to template C.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a hand-made way to avoid making class `C` a template:

```
struct C {
    template <typename Func>
    void foo(Func fun) {
        _myFunc = static_cast <void*>(&fun);
        stub = call <Func>;
    }

    void someOtherThing() {
        stub(_myFunc);
    }

private:
    void* _myFunc;
    void (*stub)(void*);

    template <typename F>
    static void call(void* f) {
        (*static_cast <F*>(f))();
    }
};

struct S {
    void operator()() { std::cout << "in S" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    S s;
    C myClass;
    myClass.foo(s);
    myClass.someOtherThing();
}
```

When you call `foo()`, type `Func` is "stored" inside the template static function `call`, a pointer to (an instatiation of) which is stored in `stub`. The latter is called by `someOtherThing` to actually invoke `_myFunc`, which is nothing but plain `void*`. For this to happen, `_myFunc` is first cast back to the correct type, which is only known inside `call`'s body.

The only catch is that using pointers to functions there can be no inlining for `stub(...)` call.

Comment: This is effectively the same thing as using `std::function`, except that it doesn't work for function pointers.

Comment: Actually, it plain doesn't work at all, since `_myFunc` is a pointer to the argument to the constructor, which is a local variable. Just use `std::function` like a normal person.

Comment: This use of `void*` is very much C style, dangerous, and very bad practice. C++ provides `std::function` for this type of thing. **Never do this in C++.**

Comment: @Xeo I only wanted to demonstrate how this works. To make it generic, of course you could do a lot things given e.g. 1000 lines of code - or just use `std::function`.

Comment: @Puppy/Walter It's almost one year later, but take a look at [llvm::function_ref](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#the-function-ref-class-template). If you check its [source code](http://llvm.org/doxygen/STLExtras_8h_source.html#l00068), it's identical to my answer here. The authors are aware of `std::function`, yet they choose to **do this** in C++. So they must not be **normal persons**, right?